# How do I remove the white border around this input? (JSFiddle provided)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

http://jsfiddle.net/gn3LL/

```
 .error { background-color: red; }

 <input id="firstname" class="custom error" name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
```

There is a small but noticeable white border around the inside of the input box. How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just user border:none

```
  input {border:none;}
```

Or in your error class

```
 .error { background-color: red; border:none;}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gn3LL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
border:0px;
```

or

```
border:0px solid #000;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have **two class attributes** in a single element.

It is not valid based on [w3.org's 8.2.4.35 Attribute name state](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attribute-name-state).

> ... if there is already an attribute on the token with the exact same
>   name, then this is a parse error and the new attribute must be removed
>   from the token.

So you need to combine them like this -

```
 <input id="firstname" class="custom error input-xlarge" 
     name="first_name" type="text" placeholder="" >
```

### Back to original question

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uF89a/1/)

```
.error { background-color: red; border: 0; }
```

OR

```
input[type="text"] { border: 0; }
```

OR *(After you combine them into one)*

```
.input-xlarge { border: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.error { background-color:red; border:0; }
```

Comment: I'd beg to differ. `border:0;` is the answer. Doesn't need to be complicated.